# Vue reactivity issue: slot in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following setup:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ 'It updates here: ' + controlValue }}

    <modal v-bind:is-open="showModal" v-on:close-modal="showModal = false"
    >
        <template v-slot:body>
            {{ 'Doesn\'t update here ' + controlValue }}
            <control
                    name="tag-error-control"
                    type="radio"
                    v-bind:options="options"
                    v-model="controlValue"
            />
        </template>
    </modal>
</div>
```

When initially mounting components, controlValue is passed down correctly to Control. What's happening after that, is when clicking one of the radio buttons in Control, the value gets updated, input event is dispatched and controlValue in the main Vue component is updated, but it doesn't trickle down into the Modal and Control components (since Modal doesn't re-render). When I close the modal, then it re-renders and I can see the value trickling down to Modal and Control.

=======================
edit

Did some more tests. Actually it doesn't relate to the Control at all. It's the same with a simple input.

```
<div id="app">
    {{ 'It updates here: ' + controlValue }}

    <modal v-bind:is-open="showModal" v-on:close-modal="showModal = false"
    >
        <template v-slot:body>
            {{ 'Doesn\'t update here ' + controlValue }}
                <input name="radio" type="radio" value="1" v-model="controlValue" />
                <input name="radio" type="radio" value="2" v-model="controlValue" />
                <input name="radio" type="radio" value="3" v-model="controlValue" />
                <input name="radio" type="radio" value="4" v-model="controlValue" />
        </template>
    </modal>
</div>
```

I ran out of ideas on how to fix this. Any clues?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: doesnt this give your any error ´<template>{{nfdjksnfkj}}<div></div></template>´ is invalid syntax, you have to encapsulate it into *one* node

Comment: Could you post the structure of these components?

Comment: try updating `controlValue ` using `set` fn. Another non-recommended way can be: `forceUpdate` the modal component. Would be able to help in a better way if you can post the code for the components & how you are updating the `controlValue ` var.

Comment: @YomS. You can find the src for both components here: https://github.com/teamfurther/cinderblock/tree/dev/src/js/components

Comment: @ShivamSingh it's updated by emitting the input event. See the link in the above comment for source code.

Answer (score 0):

So, as I suspected, the issue was with my slot scopes.

I had to look into https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots.

I changed my Modal component to have a slot prop on the slot.

```
<slot name="body" v-bind:slotProps="slotProps"></slot>
```

and then use it like this:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ 'It updates here: ' + controlValue }}

    <modal v-bind:is-open="showModal" v-bind:slot-props="controlValue" v-on:close-modal="showModal = false"
    >
        <template v-slot:body>
            {{ 'Doesn\'t update here ' + controlValue }}
            <control
                    name="tag-error-control"
                    type="radio"
                    v-bind:options="options"
                    v-model="controlValue"
            />
        </template>
    </modal>
</div>
```